# How to use GADTs across modules in OCaml without raising warnings?

Tags: types, pattern-matching, ocaml, compiler-warnings, gadt

I have two files: gadt1.ml and gadt2.ml and the second depends on the first.

gadt1.ml:

```
type never
type _ t1 = A1 : never  t1 | B1 : bool t1
type _ t2 = A2 : string t2 | B2 : bool t2
let get1 : bool t1 -> bool = function B1 -> true
let get2 : bool t2 -> bool = function B2 -> true
```

gadt2.ml:

```
let get1 : bool Gadt1.t1 -> bool = function Gadt.B1 -> true
let get2 : bool Gadt1.t2 -> bool = function Gadt.B2 -> true
```

when I compile using ocaml 4.02.3 (`ocamlbuild gadt2.native`), I get a warning 8 about the function Gadt2.get1 not being exhaustive. I am quite puzzled that `Gadt2.get1` raises a warning while `Gadt1.get1` and `Gadt2.get2` don't.

My assumption was that the empty type `never` cannot be equal to `bool` so `Gadt2.get1` should not raise a warning. On the other hand, if I call `Gadt2.get1` with argument `A1`, I get a type error (as desired). Is the warning expected behaviour or a bug? What did I miss?

By the way, adding `-principal` to the compile flags does not change anything.

Comment: I suspect it is a bug.  You should ask the question at caml-list mailing list.   Who is in charge of OCaml GADT is not watching SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Gadt2` can only see the interface of `Gadt1`, not its implementation. The interface looks something like this:

```
type never
type _ t1 = A1 : never  t1 | B1 : bool t1
type _ t2 = A2 : string t2 | B2 : bool t2
val get1 : bool t1 -> bool
val get2 : bool t2 -> bool
```

Note that `type never` is abstract -- there's nothing to stop an implementation giving it a RHS. In particular, you could, inside gadt1.ml, write `type never = bool`, at which point it becomes reasonable to pass `A1` to `get1`, and so `get1` needs to be prepared for that possibility.

By contrast, `string` is a non-abstract type: it has a known representation, so it can't possibly be equal to `bool`, and so `A2` could never be passed to `get2`.

What you seem to be trying to do with `never` is declare a type which is not abstract but *empty*, exposing its representation as having no constructors at all. Unfortunately that just isn't well-supported by OCaml; the ability to define a type that locally the compiler can tell is empty is a bit of a quirk, and not really mentioned in the [manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/typedecl.html#sec150). There's no way to express "this type is empty" in a module signature.

**update:** my belief is that this has since changed, and you can now write:

```
type never = |
```

to indicate that `never` really is an empty type, and not an abstract one.

Answer (score 2):

As Ben says, the problem is that in a signature `type t` is abstract rather than empty. One alternative is to define a type that is uninhabited:

```
module One = struct
  type never = { impossible : 'a . 'a }
  type _ t1 = A1 : never  t1 | B1 : bool t1
  type _ t2 = A2 : string t2 | B2 : bool t2
  let get1 : bool t1 -> bool = function B1 -> true
  let get2 : bool t2 -> bool = function B2 -> true
end

module Two = struct
  let get1 : bool One.t1 -> bool = function One.B1 -> true
  let get2 : bool One.t2 -> bool = function One.B2 -> true
end
```

This doesn't give any exhaustiveness warnings.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into the same problem today and spent quite a lot of time looking for a solution.
As Ben and gsg said, it is indeed due to the fact that the `type never` is abstract.
The most elegant solution in my opinion is to define it as a private variant.

```
type never = private Never
```

This solves the exhaustiveness warning and makes it clear you removed the possibility of creating a variable of this type.